# String comparison is returning false

Tags: javascript, string, comparison

Why is this returning false all the time?

```
var a = new String("17-0069,,Alex Libengood,Travel from - Meadors Office - to - 201 Hildebrand Dr, Bonneau SC,Site inspection,,0.55,/mile,0,miles,,1,17-0069><><Alex Libengood><Travel from - Meadors Office - to - 201 Hildebrand Dr, Bonneau SC><Site inspection><0.55><1,Mileage").trim();
var b = new String("17-0069,,Alex Libengood,Travel from - Meadors Office - to - 201 Hildebrand Dr, Bonneau SC,Site Inspection,,0.55,/mile,0,miles,,1,17-0069><><Alex Libengood><Travel from - Meadors Office - to - 201 Hildebrand Dr, Bonneau SC><Site Inspection><0.55><1,Mileage").trim();
if (a === b){
   return true;
} else {
   return false;
}
```

It's the same string!

I've seen other questions answered by using the trim() method, but it's not working for me.  It's like there are hidden characters somewhere in the strings that I can't see.  But when I test the lengths, they are both 255 characters long.

Comment: The characters of the string are the same, but those characters are stored in different _String Objects_ - that are not equivalent.

Comment: @RandyCasburn No, `trim()` does not return an object

Comment: Cause the strings *are different!* There must be some invisible character / different encoding.

Comment: @Bergi - I didn't scroll :-/

Comment: Don't create strings with the `String` constructor. There is no need for that.

Comment: It's `Inspection` vs `inspection`, no invisible character, just capital vs lowercase `i`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> It's the same string!

No, it's not. Look closely:

```
"17-0069,,Alex Libengood,Travel from - Meadors Office - to - 201 Hildebrand Dr, Bonneau SC,Site inspection,,0.55,/mile,0,miles,,1,17-0069><><Alex Libengood><Travel from - Meadors Office - to - 201 Hildebrand Dr, Bonneau SC><Site inspection><0.55><1,Mileage"
"17-0069,,Alex Libengood,Travel from - Meadors Office - to - 201 Hildebrand Dr, Bonneau SC,Site Inspection,,0.55,/mile,0,miles,,1,17-0069><><Alex Libengood><Travel from - Meadors Office - to - 201 Hildebrand Dr, Bonneau SC><Site Inspection><0.55><1,Mileage"
                                                                                                ^                                                                                                                                    ^
```

Those are not hidden characters, they're simply different cases of `i`/`I`. Found with

```
for (let i=0; i<255; i++) if (a[i] != b[i]) console.log(i, a[i], b[i])
```

Comment: Well, that's embarrassing :0  I thought I checked for that like 15 times, and still didn't see it.  That code snippet is a good idea to check for it though.  Thanks @Bergi!